# Bitmap потребление памяти

Tags: java, android, память, bitmap

Сравнил сколько ОЗУ потребуется для загрузки в память изображения (800 на 960) в андроиде посредством Bitmap и на ПК Swing посредством BufferedImage. Сжатия никакие не использовал. Так вот на андроиде потребовалось целых 46 мегабайт, тогда как на свинге только 3 мегабайта. Как так получается, ведь если каждый пиксель занимает 4 байта, то это изображение без сжатий должно занимать всего-лишь 3 мегабайта. Откуда столько много лишней памяти то берется (с учетом того, что на андроид устройствах памяти меньше и должно наоборот по максимуму её экономить) и какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: Не видя код, сказать нельзя

Comment: Вот здесь хорошо объяснили почему так происходит https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280989/13483092

Comment: @Kromster
Примерно вот так на андроиде: https://pastebin.com/W9trGscm
И вот так на Swing: https://pastebin.com/xC2gqgCA

Comment: @Circassian , да действительно, по данному совету уже намного лучше, спасибо!